# store_url does not render link correctly

Tags: magento-1.9, cms, static-block, cms-block, link

I am using this link in my static CMS block

```
<a href="{{store_url='produkte/insektenschutz/fenster/spannrahmen.html'}}">
```

but it renders as `https://www.mysite.de/produkte/insektenschutz/fenster/`

Why is `spannrahmen.html` cut off?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add **`store direct_url`** instead of **`store_url`**

```
<a href="{{store direct_url='produkte/insektenschutz/fenster/spannrahmen.html'}}">
```

`spannrahmen.html` will show after this.

Comment: Sorry, @HirenKadivar already answered faster.

Comment: He edited his answer, I answered correctly before. But it's ok, the point is, your issue is resolved now

Answer (score 8):

Try adding this to your block:

```
<a href="{{store direct_url="produkte/insektenschutz/fenster/spannrahmen.html"}}">Link to Base URL</a>
```